# GUI Builder: File Upload, Submit Button and DoPost issue

Tags: google-apps-script

There is something I do not understand with the Apps Script GUI Builder.
I am trying to have a File Upload and I cannot have it working.
Basic setup: form panel, a flow panel, a file upload, a submit button.
I did not put any Events on On Mouse Click (I understood that the doPost catch it by default).

The associated functions:

```
function appBVFileUpload2() {
   var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('File Upload');
   app.add(app.loadComponent("ImportationBV")); // load the GUI
   mydoc.show(app); 
}

function doPost(e) {
  // data returned is a blob for FileUpload Form
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile; // thefile is the name of the File Upload Object
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob); // Generate the Error <<<
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app; 
}
```

So I always get an error when clicking on the submit button:

> Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred

**Important note**: the error is generated by the line `var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);` . So I suspect either the data from the file upload object is not received properly.

Interestingly enough the example provided by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_fileupload) works for me. Meaning that if the GUI is done via code and **not** via the GUI builder the upload works.

I triple checked everything, I am really puzzled, and start to think there may be a bug with the File Upload via the GUI Builder. Any help?

Thanks for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes often when the **name** of the widget is not what it should be, you could try to log the e.parameter to see what is in it...`Logger.log(e.parameter);`
Check also that the widget's **name** has no accidental space in it...

EDIT : following your comments, I tested it here and it works. Could you please check if you have the same setup (component tree, names...) , here is a screen cap. :
[image]

Comment: note that [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_fileupload) shows the very same example build from script editor, it might help you to try it

Comment: Thanks. The **name** of the fileupload object is correct, the **name** of the component has no space in it. The error comes from the line `var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);` and gives me _The page at https://docs.google.com says: Error encountered: An unexpected error occurred_ . Could it be a permission problem with Docs?

Comment: Have you tried the script shown in the doc ? does it throw the same error ?

Comment: No problems with the File Upload when made with code. Only problem when using the GUI Builder to create the file upload form. Indeed, the `e.parameter` object do not have the file with it. So it's not transmitted with the form. Could it be a bug since I have this problem only with the GUI Builder?

Comment: I'm going to give it a try, I'll tell you what I found a bit later

Comment: Thanks Serge. My issue was that I was relying on the Base ID _name_ of the object and forgot to put the **name** in _Input Field_ section!!!